# Typescript compilation error - TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've update the typescript package to the latest version, and now I encounter this error during compilation:

`TS2769: No overload matches this call`

```
src/utils/search_module/index.ts:24:26 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.


Overload 1 of 4, '(params?: Search<RequestBody<Record<string, any>>> | undefined, options?: TransportRequestOptions | undefined): TransportRequestPromise<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | Buffer | Readable | Record<string, any> | undefined'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(callback: callbackFn<Record<string, any>, Context>): TransportRequestCallback', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ index: string; body: unknown; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'callbackFn<Record<string, any>, Context>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'index' does not exist in type 'callbackFn<Record<string, any>, Context>'.

24             return await client.search({
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
25                 index: ELASTIC_SEARCH_INDEX,
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
26                 body,
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
27             });
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

this is the code:

```
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
import nr from 'newrelic';
import config from 'config';

import constants from '../../../config/constants';
import { Hit } from './types';

export { search };

const ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOST = config.get<string>(constants.ELASTIC_SEARCH_ENDPOINT);
const ELASTIC_SEARCH_INDEX = config.get<string>(constants.ELASTIC_SEARCH_INDEX);

const client = new Client({
    node: ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOST,
});

async function search<SourceResponse, HighlightResponse>(body: unknown): Promise<Hit<SourceResponse, HighlightResponse>> {
    const result = await nr.startSegment('search_module:search', true, async () => {
        return await client.search({
            index: ELASTIC_SEARCH_INDEX,
            body,
        });
    });
}
```

I looked in the definition of '@elastic/elasticsearch', yet could not find a way to resolve this error.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `body` parameter for your `search` function is `unknown`. But the required type is [requestParams.d.ts](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/9fea1aedc0eb328f6b3e855b775be59312e2559b/api/requestParams.d.ts#L2039)

```
export interface Search<T = RequestBody> extends Generic {
  //...
  body?: T;
}
```

So the `body` property has `RequestBody` type constraint.

`RequestBody` type:

> export type RequestBody<T = Record<string, any>>  = T | string | Buffer | ReadableStream

`body` can not be `unknown`. It must be one of the `Record<string, any>`, `string`, `Buffer`, and `ReadableStream` types.

That's why you got `no overload signature matches your call` error.